# Change the text from child nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following markup:

```
<label class="radio">
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="month_type" value="0" checked="checked">
On day 5
</label>
```

and i need to change the text from 'On day 5' to 'On day 6'. The selection needs to be upward from input to label.

I have tried:

```
$("input[name='month_type']").parent().text(''); // the result is an empty string
$("input[name='month_type']").parent().contents().filter(function(){
return this.nodeType === 3; // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL 
})​.remove();​
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("input[name='month_type']")[0].nextSibling.data = ' On day 6';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W3WLD/1/

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/4s2eV

**JS:-**

```
$("input[name='month_type']").parent().html(function(){
    return $(this).html().replace("On day 5","On day 6");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#textchange").click(function(){
$('input[name=month_type]').parent().html('<input class="radio" type="radio" name="month_type" value="0" checked="checked">On day 6');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4j37C/

Answer (score 0):

to change the text you'd better try javascript itself instead of jQuery. you might know your label has 2 childNode. the first one is nodType = 1 the last one nodeType = 3. try this and you'll get what you want:

```
$("input[name='month_type']").parent()[0].lastChild.textContent = "On day 6";
```

Comment: actually you label has 3 childNode the first one is a empty text node and the next is your input node.